# Dynamically setting a key in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query

I'm trying to dynamically build a query for [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) in [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). The function that creates it is:

```
    app.set('searchTerm', function (field, str){
        var i, searchTerm, keywords;
        keywords = str.split(' ');
        searchTerm = {field : str , _keywords : keywords};
        return searchTerm;
    });
```

My problem is that the object constructed ends up with the string 'field' as a key, not the passed argument. How do I get it to evaluate the argument?

Comment: Where's `terms` defined?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, sorry, I found a close one to that but they always started with at least part of the key declared as a string. I didn't understand that it has to be a two step process... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
app.set('searchTerm', function (field, str){
    var i, searchTerm, keywords;
    keywords = str.split(' ');
    searchTerm = {_keywords: keywords};
    searchTerm[field] = str;
    console.dir(searchTerm);
    return searchTerm;
});
```

Comment: You could use: `searchTerm = {_keywords: str.split(' ')};` to make the `keywords` variable redundant. :-)